# Single Chinese character determined as length 2 in Java/Scala String

Tags: java, scala, character-encoding

I'm trying to split out all the Chinese characters from a String, but I bumped into a strange situation for the character

```
scala> ""
res1: String = 

scala> res1.length
res2: Int = 2

scala> res1.getBytes
res3: Array[Byte] = Array(-16, -91, -111, -82)

scala> res1(0)
res4: Char = ?

scala> res1(1)
res5: Char = ?
```

It's a single character, but Java/Scala determine it as two unknown characters. And usually I see Chinese character taking three bytes in UTF-8, but this character takes four.

Hence, I can't split a String and find this single character. Even worse, when using `myString.replaceAll("[^\\p{script=Han}]", "")` to kick out all the non-Chinese characters, the second part of  is replaced and it becomes an invalid String.

Is there any solution to this? I'm using openjdk-8-jdk on Ubuntu.

Comment: This is called a [surrogate pair](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-unicode/) (as you can confirm with `Character.isSurrogatePair(res1(0), res1(1))`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For length you should use

```
string.codePointCount(0, string.length());
```

For replacement it is best to avoid regex, which is char-based. You could write a loop relying on `String#offsetByCodePoints()` and manually remove characters based on `String.codePointAt()` and `Character.isIdeographic()`.

Comment: `string.codePointCount` is very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have encountered a Surrogate Pair. That character is [U+2546E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2546e/index.htm), which as you see, is a lot bigger than 2^16. It is represented in a Java or Scala String as the sequence 0xD855 0xDC6E.

If you want a regex library that handles this sort of thing transparently, I happen to know where to find one: [TCL regex ported to Java](https://github.com/basis-technology-corp/tcl-regex-java). If you don't want to go there, you need to use the Code Point methods of String and Character in java to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

The Java standard library unicode support predates the current standard and as such the support for astral (non-BMP) characters is... limited; several APIs will treat them as the individual surrogate pairs as you saw. If you are doing extensive string manipulation it might be best to use [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/home/why-use-icu4j), which I understand offers regexes with full unicode support.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Marko's answer, here's an example to split a String:

```
scala> val x = "硓abc"
x: String = 硓abc

scala> (0 to x.codePointCount(0, x.length)).map(c => x.offsetByCodePoints(0, c)).sliding(2).map(w => x.substring(w.head, w.last)).toList
res1: List[String] = List(硓, , a, b, c)
```

And to determine if each character is a CJKV:

```
scala> (0 until x.codePointCount(0, x.length)).map(c => x.offsetByCodePoints(0, c)).map(i => Character.isIdeographic(x.codePointAt(i))).toList
res2: List[Boolean] = List(true, true, false, false, false)
```

Comment: hi, Is it Java1.8? If I use java 1.7, what the syntax should be or any other method??

Answer (score -2):

i think you want to replace/split the string.That you can do without knowing the length of the string.Because java takes sequence of string also to replace a particular char or sequence of char in a string. For example :-`public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String s="";
    System.out.println(s.replace("", "k"));

}
}
```

`
And if you want to split the String then go for stringtokenizer.For example :-

```
StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer("your sentence or String","the problematic char/string");
```

Answer (score -4):

Probable that this character is invalid or unsupported in UTF-8 but supported in UTF-16, resulting in some incompatibilities between JVM and Scala shell. Is your system big- or little-endian? Also you could try getting the character's Unicode Code Point and check if it is UTF-8 or UTF-16. Also, Chinese has compounded letters, like Japanese Kanji and Furigana, so that may also be a part of your problem.

Comment: All UTF-16 characters are equally supported in UTF-8.